# Full page column in materialize css

Tags: css, materialize

First here is the screenshot of what is wrong with the current code
[image]
and here is the code that is associated with the same

```
  <nav class="blue darken-3">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Chatter</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">view_module</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3 red">1</div>
  <div class="col s9 indigo" style="height:100%">4</div>
</div>
```

first i don't see the reason why 4 is a little below 1. This bug resolves when i add a margin of 10 px to top of row, but the thing is that red menu bar should be colored and therefore i don't wan't any white space in between that.

The second question, that i am not sure about how to do that the correct way is that i want both blue and red to cover the entire height on the browser window. Is there anyway how to do the same in materialize , or if not please help me with how that is possible.

Answer (score 10):

To set the height to full view add this CSS

```
.col.s3.red, .col.s9.indigo {
  min-height: 100vh; /* use "vh" instead of % */
}
```

It will help setting the height to view port height.

Answer (score 2):

These solutions work so long as the content in either of the div's does not overflow the browser window and cause it to scroll.

In order for both columns to fill 100% of the page height (not viewport height) I found this:
[CSS: equal height columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846068/css-equal-height-columns)

Add the following code to the parent div (row)

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;  /*or use calc(100vh - header_height)*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using:

```
.full-width {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px !important;
}
```

You need to use !`important` because .row .col has a min-height: 1px;

```
  <div class="col s3 yellow lighten-4 full-width">
  A
  </div>

  <div class="col s9 grey lighten-4 full-width">
  B
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution used 100% of the viewport's larger dimension.

```css
.myColumnFormat {
  min-height: 100vmax;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <h4>This solution uses Materialize</h4>
</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class='col myColumnFormat blue s6'>
    <ul>
      <li>This column is blue</li>
      <li>This column's background colour is full length</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class='col green s5 offset-s1 '>
    <ul>
      <li>This column is green</li>
      <li>This column's background colour ends at the end of this list</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Second question, add this in your CSS-File:

```
div.col.s3.red {
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}

div.col.s9.indigo {
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It gives a height of 100% to the two elements, it should work in newer Browsers. For older Browser you could add **min-height** to it.

First Question, the nav elements have a line-height of 64px, you could reduce it as you like in your CSS-File:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    line-height: 44px;
}
```

Comment: First part of the question is working properly but the second part is not. Height too 100% is not working its still the same.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/w0v2e5j7/ and it works perfect there is no margin between blue one and header.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez here is the snapshot https://www.anony.ws/image/Jz2Y . The pen works but the issue is that by setting min-height to 500 px, If there is no content it remains at 500 px and if content overflows, it becomes more than that, What i need is them to perfectly align to height for any browser irrespective of content contained within :)

Comment: Try this jquery code:https://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/ you have to change the selector

Answer (score 0):

To get full height you can do following. **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/w0v2e5j7/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<nav class="blue darken-3">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Chatter</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">view_module</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></a></li>
        <li><a nohref><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3 red">1</div>
  <div class="col s9 indigo">4</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window_size = $(window).height();
    $('.col').height(window_size);
});
```

Comment: you did not consider the height of nav in this case, which becomes diffrent for diffrent viewport. So actually the stuff overflows in a browser. The main canvas is for chat and will be having its own scrollbar so i don't think that that might be the best option here

Answer (score 0):

```
var resizeColumn = function () {
    my_column_el.height($(window).height() - my_column_el.offset().top);
  };

  $(window).on('resize.column', _.debounce(resizeColumn, 300));

  resizeColumn();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As with Bootstrap, most Materialize styling starts with a container.  If the container is not 100% then child divs will not be either.  This styling will start you off with 100% width and 100% height:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper-100vh {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Remove "width: 100%;" in the container css and it will be 70% wide (default).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="valign-wrapper content-wrapper-100vh">
    <div class="row center-align">
        <div class="col l12">
            <div class="my-title">Centered/Middle Title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```