# CSS: equal height columns

Tags: css, materialize

In this [website](http://ehdigital.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch) I would like to define an equal Height for the columns with the questions.

I am using Materialize CSS as Framework.

Is this possible?

This is my actual HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="section">

  <!--   Icon Section   -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 question-one">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
        <h5 class="center">How can I buy simple products fast and easy?</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m6 question-two">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></i></h2>
        <h5 class="center">How can I buy my ongoing demand in some minutes?</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 question-three">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
        <h5 class="center">How can I get mobile access to documentation / spare parts of my devices?</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m6 question-four">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
        <h5 class="center">How can I find the fitting product to my application?</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<br><br>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.question-one {
 padding: 85px 85px 85px 85px !important;
 background-color: #009ee3;
}

.question-two {
 padding: 85px 85px 85px 85px !important;
 background-color: #009ee3;
}

.question-three {
 padding: 85px 85px 85px 85px !important;
 background-color: #009ee3;
}

.question-four {
 padding: 85px 85px 85px 85px !important;
 background-color: #009ee3;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 51):

Flexbox was born for this. This is how I approached it on MaterializeCSS.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and on the parent row add

```
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer. Worked for me too. +1

Comment: Mark it as Correct Ans Worked for Me as well 1++

Comment: Yes, passing by here in 2020. This should be the marked right answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Please see below. I have redefined your CSS so you can add as many questions as you want. When the `class` question-xxx (where xxx is anything) is used, the CSS will be applied.

```css
[class*="question-"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #009ee3;
}
h2, h5 { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <!--   Icon Section   -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m6 question-one">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
          <h5 class="center">How can I buy simple products fast and easy?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col s12 m6 question-two">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <h2 class="center light-blue-text">
            </i>
          </h2>
          <h5 class="center">How can I buy my ongoing demand in some minutes?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m6 question-three">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
          <h5 class="center">How can I get mobile access to documentation / spare parts of my devices?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 question-four">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <h2 class="center light-blue-text"></h2>
          <h5 class="center">How can I find the fitting product to my application?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```